# Twitter API returns null for coordinates and retweets

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm having issues getting accurate location from tweets.

I can easily get `tweet.user.location`, however `tweet.coordinates` is always undefined/null.
I know I can geolocate the city, however, it is not very accurate.

I am having the same issue finding the original tweet, assuming some tweets have been retweeted. `tweet.retweeted` is always null, even over hundreds of searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user has to **explicitly** share its location while tweeting for `tweet.coordinates` to be equal to the tweet exact location, so it makes sense many tweets will have empty `coordinates`.

On the Twitter application, tweets which have their location shared will have the location icon on the right side. Like this:

[image]

If you query the API for timeline with shared location statuses such at the one above, you should see the coordinates data.

The `user.location` field is different and holds the location user has defined on its profile.

Read the [`Geo Guidelines`](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/geo-developer-guidelines) of the API.

As for detecting a retweeted tweet:

- The `retweeted` field will return `true` if **a tweet got retweeted**
- To detect if a tweet is a retweet of other tweet, you should check the `retweeted_status` field